# Appending htmlfragment to an element

Tags: javascript, html

I am loading json data and displaying them on site inside div.

I decided to store the data inside an htmlfragment using

```
var docFragment = new DocumentFragment();
function createFullList(){
   var aside       = document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0];
   for( x in obj ){
      createInfoElement( docFragment , obj[x].general , obj[x].job );
   }
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.appendChild(docFragment);
   aside.innerHTML += div;
}
```

crateInfoElement just creates div and append it to docFragment.
What is troublling me is when i want to append an documentFragment into its supposed holder ( aside variable ).
It does not display all divs inside it instead of it just

> [object HTMLDivElement]

I do not have much experience with fragments , but using example from MDN

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]; // assuming it exists
var docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var browserList = ["Internet Explorer", "Mozilla Firefox", "Safari", "Chrome", "Opera"];

browserList.forEach(function(e) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = e;
  docfrag.appendChild(li);
});

ul.appendChild(docfrag);
```

it does display ul and li elements inside it not just

> [object HTMLDivElement]

as in my case. What is causing this behavior?

createInfoElement looks like this

```
function createInfoElement( parent , name , job ){
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.setAttribute("class","left_info");

   var p  = document.createElement("p");
       p.setAttribute("class","name");
       p.innerHTML = name.firstName + " " + name.lasName;

   var p_two = document.createElement("p");
       p_two.setAttribute("class","job");
       p_two.innerHTML = job.title;

   div.appendChild(p);
   div.appendChild(p_two);
   parent.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: instead of `aside.innerHTML += div;` try using `aside.innerHTML += div.innerHTML;` and let me know what changes.

Comment: interessting , this works thanks. But why it did not work when i just used aside.innerHTML += docFragment? Also could you explain why directly inserting div into innerHTML does not work but its content does?

Comment: Because div as you had it was a Javascript Dom object. You wanted it's content, and js isnt smart enough to know that so it just put the element through the "toString" method.